# Apache CXF Post issue

Tags: java, apache, cxf

I'm using apache cxf WebClient(org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient) for POST an JSON String.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(url);
client.path("");
client.header("Content-Length", data.getBytes().length);
client.header("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
client.post(data);
```

If the data size is more, I'm getting 411-Length Required response. Else if the data size is less its posting fine.

Kindly let me know what is missing here.

Regards,
Siva.